# How to read file size using Fast API UploadFile class without reading whole file into memory?

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, fastapi

Atm I am using .read() then len() to get the size of a file using UploadFile type. This reads the whole rile into memory which (for some reason) is affecting my upload to S3. Is there another way of getting the file size?

`file_type = uploaded_file.content_type`

`contents = await uploaded_file.read()`

`file_size = len(contents)`

The full function is below. Removing the 'reading the file' functionality fixes the file upload to S3. Otherwise it uploads uploads, but 0 bytes.

```
@router.post("/upload_incoming_file_to_s3")
async def create_upload_file(uploaded_file: UploadFile):

    if not uploaded_file:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="No file uploaded")

    file_type = uploaded_file.content_type
    contents = await uploaded_file.read()
    file_size = len(contents)
    

    if file_size > 10 * MB:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="File too large")

    if file_type not in SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPES:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Unsupported file type")
    
    file_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    file_extension = SUPPORTED_FILE_TYPES[file_type]
    file_name = f"{file_uuid}.{file_extension}"

    extra_information = {
        
        "file_name": uploaded_file.filename,
    }
    print({"extra_information": extra_information})

    try: 
        
        s3.upload_fileobj(uploaded_file.file, BUCKET_NAME, file_name, ExtraArgs={"Metadata": extra_information})
        # upload file to db
    except Exception as e:
        print({"error": e})
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Error uploading file")
    return {"uploaded": uploaded_file.filename}
```

Comment: `uploaded_file.size`? Also, the reason why reading the file breaks your upload is because this leaves the current read pointer at the end of the file. You can use `uploaded_file.file.seek(0)` to reset the read pointer to the start of the file before giving it to the s3 library.